# Преобразовать строку в которой заключен ассоциативный массив в массив PHP

Tags: php, массивы, строки

Всем доброго дня. Столкнулся с задачей преобразования строки с массивом

```
$str = "array('3787' => array('3250', '3251'),'3245' => array('827', '3264'), '3788' => array(''))";
```

в обычный массив php

```
$arr = array('3787' => array('3250', '3251'),'3245' => array('827', '3264'), '3788' => array(''));
```

Входные строки могут быть другими.
Как я могу это сделать? 
Всем заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Каким образом Вы приводите массив к строке? Если через `json_encode`, то можете просто раскодировать. А если именно текстом - то могу написать примерно как.

Comment: @Denis640Kb Боюсь, что это не json_encode. Массив передается именно строкой. Буду крайне благодарен, если подскажете, как это можно преобразовать.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266381/string-array-to-real-array

Answer (score 0):

Можете воспользоваться функцией [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php)

```
$arr = eval("return $str;");
```

> **Предостережение** Языковая конструкция eval() может быть очень опасной,
>   поскольку позволяет выполнить произвольный код. Использование данной
>   функции не рекомендуется. Если вы полностью убеждены, что нет другого
>   способа, кроме использования этой конструкции, обратите особое
>   внимание на то, чтобы не передавать какие-либо данные, предоставленые
>   пользователем, без предварительной проверки.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Без `eval` лучше, на мой взгляд, в данном случае так сделать:

```
<?php
$str = "array('3787' => array('3250', '3251'),'3245' => array('827', '3264'), '3788' => array(''))";
function AndreyCh($str)
{
    $t1 = str_replace('array(', '', $str);
    $t1 = str_replace(')', '}', $t1);
    $t1 = str_replace('},', '|,', $t1);
    $t1 = str_replace("'", '', $t1);
    $t1 = str_replace("}", '', $t1);
    $newstr = explode('|,', $t1);
    $Result = array();
    foreach ($newstr as $item) {
        $t2 = explode(' => ', $item);
        $t3 = explode(',', $t2[1]);
        $Result[$t2[0]] = $t3;
    }
    return $Result;
}

print_r(AndreyCh($str));
```